# File last modified time same as download provider

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-server-2008, date-time

When I download a file the creation and last modified date & time are set to the download time.

Is there a possibility to restore the creation / modify date & time of the old owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Explorer has standard behavior when copying or moving files. However, in general, it is up to the *application* to set the creation / modify time, because Windows provides appropriate APIs for doing so.

Hence, in theory, if you have a proper chain of tools involved, it is possible. Such a toolchain would need to look like that:

- The original owner, when copying the file from its original place to the place where it is provided for download, must use a file management tool which does not alter the creation / modify time.
- The same is true for you: When downloading the file, you must use a tool which does not alter the creation / modify time, and of course, does read them at the remote location in the first place.

Regarding the first part, I think it is impossible (in the general case) to force the provider of the file to act as you like.

Regarding the second part, you could use tools like `wget` which is available for Windows either as part of `Cygwin` or as part of the `Gnu-Win32` collection; [see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping-Usage.html#Time_002dStamping-Usage) to learn how it could help solve your problem. You could also use `curl` which is available for Windows as well; its man page is [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) - take a look into the `--remote-time` option.

`wget` and `curl` probably only set the `modified` time according to your needs, but not the `created` time. If this is not sufficient, you have two options:

- Find a tool which does both (I am not aware of such programs)
- Write a script or use an another program to set the `created` time from the `modified` time, i.e. a program which is able to copy the `modified` time attribute over the `created` time attribute. There are plenty of tools for Windows which can do this, for example [this one](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html).